# What is the necklace that Mirajane wears around her neck?

Tags: fairy-tail

In Fairy Tail when Mirajane isn't in her Satans Soul form and she looks like this in the picture below-

[image]

I notice that she wears some type of necklace around her neck. What/is there a sentimental reason/value behind why she carries around this necklace on her neck?

Here are some other examples...

[image]

and another here...

[image]

Answers are appreciated. :)

Comment: seems like a normal ornament to me.. :P women like wearing them.. lol

Comment: I never see anything specific about it either, maybe debal is right. And if it's so important she will always use it, like natsu and his scarf. But when Mira change her cloth, she didn't wear it, like [this](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130105145713/fairytail/images/d/d1/Mirajane_proposal.png)

Comment: I saw that picture on the wikia. I purposely left that one out of course though because it didn't have the necklace.

Comment: @ShinobuOshino lol you spying on Mira when she's changing clothes..:P lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find any in canon references from official sources but based on general opinion here it appears to be used for general decoration and serves no exact purpose.

There are no exact references on the necklace, so this would be the most likely answer at this time, since no new information has been released yet.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that it represented her tears (after Lisanna "died") so that she would be able to smile again as her sort of "crutch", and that it was given to her by Makarov. You'll also notice that Mira stops wearing it after Lisanna comes back from Edolas, so I would say that's a pretty decent theory especially given the particular shape of this accessory.